# TYPO3 FLUX FlexForms fedext.net

Tags: typo3, flux, fedext

I'm looking for a date/time input field for my FLUX FlexForm. I need the same date/time field like the standard TYPO3 "starttime" or "endtime" (page properties). I'm using FLUX Flexforms 6.0.0 and TYPO3 6.1.5.

I've a Slideshow as an FCE and for some images I'll need a start and endtime.

https://fedext.net/viewhelpers/flux/6.0.0/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution input field with evaluation "datetime"

```
<flux:flexform.field.input name="starttime" label="" eval="datetime" default="" required="FALSE" size="24" placeholder="Start"></flux:flexform.field.input>
```

Comment: <flux:field.input name="starttime" label="" eval="datetime" default="" required="FALSE" size="24" placeholder="Start"/> in TYPO3 7.